# Dynatree drag and drop in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, dynatree

I've been starting migration from jsTree to Dynatree, because jsTree's documentation is out of date for a long time and you should spend a lot of time in debugging, but I faced with a problem - d'n'd doesn't work correctly in IE. For example, when I try to move one node to inside another, IE puts this node not inside but near (before or after). I tried the sample "Drag'n'drop 2" from [official example](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html) , it works good in Chrome, but not in IE (any version). Does anyone has experience with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the DTD of your HTML document.
I already faced this issue and I just needed to set the DTD of my HTML document to strict DTD

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```